# MvvmCross - File Plugin Nuget seems to be missing a file

Tags: mvvmcross

When trying to add the MvvmCross - File Plugin nugget package in Xamarin Studio on the Mac I get this message on any project I try it on. Is the package just missing this file?

```
Adding MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.File...
Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.CrossCore (≥ 3.5.1)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'MvvmCross.PortableSupport (≥ 3.5.1)'.
Installing 'MvvmCross.HotTuna.Plugin.File 3.5.1'.
Could not find file "/var/folders/m6/zl04rxvd30v1x04tgvdbfgjw0000gn/T/nuget/e3mdmgut.t1g/lib/portable-win+net45+wp8+win8+wpa81/Cirrious.MvvmCross.Plugins.File.dll".
```

When I download the package directly off the nuget site and unzip it manually, I find it in that folder it's looking in.

I'd appreciate suggestions as to why this is happening!

Comment: Why not try MvvmCross 4.0? It might contain a fix for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the way, I solved the problem by restarting Xamarin Studio.

Comment: I am using Visual Studio 2015 and restarting also fixed the issue. Thanks!